# How to get the inner element of a dome detached element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do as following:

```
<div id="aaa">
    <div id="bbb">
        <div id="ccc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var bbb = $('#bbb').detach();
var ccc = $('#ccc :' + bbb);
```

but I cant seem to get it right, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .find()

```
var bbb = $('#bbb').detach();
var ccc = bbb.find('#ccc');
```